# AndroidStudioでRunを実行するとJREのエラーが出て実行できない

Tags: java, flutter

AndroidStudioで空のflutterプロジェクトを作成し、Runを実行すると下記のエラーが出力します。

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

環境
Windows10
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
cmdでjava --versionを実行

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)
```

openjdk21を公式よりインストールしましたが上記の出力は変わりませんでした。

以前は空のflutterプロジェクトを実行できていたのですが、久しぶりに起動して同じ手順を行ったところエラーが出るようになりました。
直近ではAndroidStudioを最新版に更新しています。

正しく動作するような設定方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - [Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457105)

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionErrorはJVMで読みこんだクラス定義が
サポートされていないものであることを示すものです。

この場合はサポートされているのが52=Java 8 読み込もうとしたのが55 = Java 11
で、この環境では使えないよという問題かと思います。

環境変数JAVA_HOMEとPATHを正しく8を使う様に設定するか、Java 11でのコンパイル時にtargetオプションで生成するバイナリを1.8に向けるようにすることで状況改善されないでしょうか。